# Using explicit del in python on local variables

Tags: python, coding-style

What are the best practices and recommendations for using explicit `del` statement in python? I understand that it is used to remove attributes or dictionary/list elements and so on, but sometimes I see it used on local variables in code like this:

```
def action(x):
    result = None
    something = produce_something(x)
    if something:
        qux = foo(something)
        result = bar(qux, something)
        del qux
    del something
    return result
```

Are there any serious reasons for writing code like this?

Edit: consider `qux` and `something` to be something "simple" without a `__del__` method.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't remember when I last used `del` -- the need for it is rare indeed, and typically limited to such tasks as cleaning up a module's namespace after a needed `import` or the like.

In particular, it's **not** true, as another (now-deleted) answer claimed, that

> Using `del` is the only way to make sure
>   a object's `__del__` method is called

and it's very important to understand this.  To help, let's make a class with a `__del__` and check when it is called:

```
>>> class visdel(object):
...   def __del__(self): print 'del', id(self)
... 
>>> d = visdel()
>>> a = list()
>>> a.append(d)
>>> del d
>>>
```

See?  `del` doesn't "make sure" that `__del__` gets called: `del` removes one reference, and only the removal of the **last** reference causes `__del__` to be called.  So, also:

```
>>> a.append(visdel())
>>> a[:]=[1, 2, 3]
del 550864
del 551184
```

when the last reference does go away (including in ways that don't involve `del`, such as a slice assignment as in this case, or other rebindings of names and other slots), **then** `__del__` gets called -- whether `del` was ever involved in reducing the object's references, or not, makes *absolutely* no difference whatsoever.

So, unless you specifically need to clean up a namespace (typically a module's namespace, but conceivably that of a class or instance) for some specific reason, don't bother with `del` (it can be occasionally handy for removing an item from a container, but I've found that I'm often using the container's `pop` method or item or slice assignment even for *that*!-).

Comment: Alex, pretty soon Python's technical writers are going to be without jobs ; ) Thanks for another great answer.

Comment: @Dana, sure hope not, since I'm such a writer myself;-). @jhwist, thanks!

Comment: One could expect that all `__del__` s are called when the interpreter exits - that is not the case. By removing refs yourself you can make sure all `__del__` are called, but `with` is a much better approach.

Comment: Yep, `with` is better (`try`/`finally` in old Python versions has similar power to modern `with`, but is less handy).

Answer (score 4):

No.

I'm sure someone will come up with some silly reason to do this, e.g. to make sure someone doesn't accidentally use the variable after it's no longer valid. But probably whoever wrote this code was just confused. You can remove them.

Comment: +1: The `del` statement is for wizards only.  My advice is the same:  unless you have a problem that's actually solved by deleting an object, don't waste time on this.

Answer (score 3):

When you are running programs handling really large amounts of data ( to my experience when the totals memory consumption of the program approaches something like 1GB) deleting some objects:
    del largeObject1
    del largeObject2
    …
can give your program the necessary breathing room to function without running out of memory. This can be the easiest way to modify a given program, in case of a “MemoryError” runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just came across a use for this. If you use locals() to return a dictionary of local variables (useful when parsing things) then del is useful to get rid of a temporary that you don't want to return.